# Clarification on Two-player Gambler's Ruin variant.

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I looked around and found many questions related to two-player variants of Gambler's Ruin but could not find what I had in mind. I needed clarification on a certain step while deriving the expression.

The following is the question:

> Consider the following game. Two players flip a coin. 
>   Player A has $N$ units and player B has $N - i$ units. 
>   If a head is flipped, player A gets a unit from player B. 
>   For a tails, player B gets a unit from player A 
>   Assume the coin flips are independent and the probability of heads = $p$ 
>  
>   Find the probability that A wins all the units.

After following the derivation mentioned below, it was relatively simple to find the expression:

$$ P(E_{i}) = \frac{1 - \left(\dfrac{1-p}{p}\right)^{i}}{1 - \left(\dfrac{1-p}{p}\right)^N} $$

I have mentioned in bold the two lines of the derivation where I could not understand how a conceptual leap was made between the two.

> Let $ E_{i} $ be the event where player A wins starting with $ i $ units. 
>  
>   $ P(E_{i}) = P(E_{i} \ | \  H) P(H) + P(E \ | \ T) P(T) \ \ $  via Bayes' Theorem. 
>   $ \therefore \ P(E_{i} \ | \ H) \cdot p + P(E_{i-1}) \cdot(1-p) = P(E_{i}) $ 
>  
>   $ \therefore \  P(E_{i} \ | \ H) \cdot p - P(E_{i}) = - P(E_{i-1}) \cdot (1-p)$ 
>   $ \therefore \  \mathbf{ p \cdot P(E_{i+1}) - P(E_{i}) = - \ (1-p) \cdot P(E_{i -1})} \ \ $ since $ \  P(E_{i} \ | \ H) = P(E_{i+1}) $  
>   $ \therefore \ \mathbf{ p \cdot \ [ \ P(E_{i+1}) - P(E_{i}) \ ] = (1-p) \cdot (P(E_{i}) - P(E_{i-1}) ) } $
>
> $ \therefore \ P(E_{i+1}) - P(E_{i}) = \frac{(1-p)}{p} (P(E_{i}) - P(E_{i-1})) $
>
> This gives us the telescoping sum: 
>   $ \require{cancel}  P(E_{2}) - P(E_{1}) = \frac{(1-p)}{p} ( \ P(E_{1}) -  \cancelto{0}{P(E_{0})} \ ) $
>   $ P(E_{3}) - P(E_{2}) = \frac{(1-p)}{p} ( \ P(E_{2}) -  P(E_{1}) \ ) = \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{2} \cdot P(E_{1}) $ 
>   $ \vdots  \qquad \qquad \vdots \qquad \qquad \vdots $ 
>   $ P(E_{i}) - P(E_{i-1}) = (\frac{1-p}{p})^{i-1} \cdot P(E_{1}) $
>
> $ P(E_{i}) - P(E_{i-1}) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} \left(\frac{(1-p)}{p}\right)^{j} \cdot P(E_{1}) $ 
>   $ \boxed{ P(E_{i}) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} \left(\frac{(1-p)}{p}\right)^{i} \cdot P(E_{1}) }$

Comment: You can get appropriately sized parentheses (or any other pair of delimiters) by preceding them by `\left` and `\right`, respectively.

Comment: Figured it would be a quick answer so didn't edit in detail. Hope it reads better now.

Comment: It does; much easier on the eyes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case @joriki's "mere arithmetic rearrangement" is still unclear, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[E_{i+1}]\cdot p-\mathbf{P}[E_i]&=-(1-p)\cdot\mathbf{P}[E_{i=1}]\\
\mathbf{P}[E_{i+1}]\cdot p+(p-1-p)\cdot\mathbf{P}[E_i]&=(p-1)\cdot\mathbf{P}[E_{i=1}]
\end{align*}
Basically we've just added and subtracted a $p$ from the coefficient of $\mathbf{P}[E_i]$ on the LHS. Factoring out a $p$,
$$p\cdot\left(\mathbf{P}[E_{i+1}]-\mathbf{P}[E_i]\right)+(p-1)\mathbf{P}[E_i]=(p-1)\cdot\mathbf{P}[E_{i=1}]$$
Now subtracting $(p-1)\mathbf{P}[E_i]$ from both sides and factoring out  -1 from the RHS,
$$p\cdot\left(\mathbf{P}[E_{i+1}]-\mathbf{P}[E_i]\right)=(1-p)\cdot\left(\mathbf{P}[E_i]-\mathbf{P}[E_{i-1}]\right)$$
It's just some subtle rearranging. As you go through more probability theory, these rearrangements become easier to see. Please comment if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line, there's no conceptual leap, just two typos – if you correct the $P$ at the beginning to a $p$ and add a closing parenthesis at the end, this line becomes a mere arithmetic rearrangement of the previous one.

In the first line, the idea is that if player $A$ has $i$ units and heads is flipped, then player $A$ has $i+1$ units, so the probability of winning with $i$ units under the condition that the next flip is heads is the probability of winning with $i+1$ units.

Comment: I fixed the typos, I understand that the second line is correct - I'm merely having problems figuring out how the the second line was derived from the first. I understand how we got the first line, theres no problem there. Would be really helpful if you edited the answer! Thanks

Comment: @UmerVakil: As I wrote, it's merely an arithmetic rearrangement; just check that the coefficients of each of the three probabilities haven't changed.